# Converting XLSX files with double quotes to CSV using Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, escaping, xlsx

I have a python script to convert Xlsx files to CSV like this -

```
import sys
import xlrd
import csv

def toCsv(xlsPath, csvPath):

   wb = xlrd.open_workbook(xlsPath)
   sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
   your_csv_file = open(csvPath, 'wb')
   wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
   for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
       rv = sh.row(rownum)
       print rv
       wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

   your_csv_file.close()

toCsv(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Some of the cells in the XLSX file contain single and double quotes. When the script runs on such cells, the output CSV comes out empty. How do I escape the single or double quotes? I tried unsuccessfully adding Dialect.doublequote = false and true as the third argument to the writer() call. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if that'll fix your problem, but don't open the output file in binary mode.

Comment: If you are using Windows, an alternative approach would be to write a Python script to get Excel to load the file and save it as CSV format.

Comment: Please give an example of a cell that fails to convert. Also, you are correct in opening the files in `wb` mode for Python 2.x.